# Python's zip() equivalent in C or C++

Tags: c++, python, zip, equivalent

I would like to zip two arrays in C++ (as in Python) using a standard library function, so is there any equivalent for Python's built-in function zip()?

Comment: I would explain what `zip` does. Not everyone knows Python.

Comment: For anybody that doesn't know, `zip()` is a transpose operation: It'll take a list: `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, and return `[[1,3],[2,4]]`

Comment: @Imagine Strictly speaking, it would return `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]` :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int **zip(int *arr1, int *arr2, int length)
{
    int **ret = new int*[length];
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = new int[2];
        ret[i][0] = arr1[i];
        ret[i][1] = arr2[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```