# Convert two vectors of int with the same length into one vector of pairs of int in C++

Tags: c++, vector, std

In C++, if I have two vectors of `int`:

```
A = [1, 2, 3 ,4]; 
B = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

How can I merge them into one vector of pairs:

```
[(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4, 4)]
```

Of course I can do that with a loop. But can we do that using suitable STL functions and iterators?

Comment: Boost has it I think, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287107/pythons-zip-equivalent-in-c-or-c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use an algorithm for this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> target;
target.reserve(A.size());
std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), std::back_inserter(target),
               [](int a, int b) { return std::make_pair(a, b); });
```

Comment: Note it doesn't actually help get rid of a loop. The loop will just be hidden in `std::transform()`. Also an explicit loop would be shorter and clearer in this particular case.

Comment: @Karadur: You cannot apply an operation to N elements without somehow iterating over the elements, that is just plain obvious: zipping two sequences cannot be done in O(1). The question is also quite clear as to what is desired: *can we do that using suitable STL functions and iterators?*. This answer does exactly that.

Comment: You could even leave out the lambda and use `make_pair` directly, no?

Comment: @jrok: I don't think so as `make_pair` would not be a valid functor, `make_pair<int, int>` on the other hand may actually work… This won't work either as the implementation of `make_pair` is based on "universal references" which become rvalue references if you take out type deduction…

Comment: @MFH Yes, I didn't mean without template parameters. Something like `make_pair<int&,int&>` ought to work, altough it's a bit strange to look at.

Comment: @jrok: that does work indeed (thanks to reference collapsing). Personally I'd prefer the lambda version…

Comment: @jrok: Using a lambda makes the operation easy to inline while using a function pointer, i.e., `std::make_pair()` directly, does not.

Comment: @Karadur: Although it probably isn't, `std::transform()` could be implemented recursively or using suitable magic. However, yes, any solution will use a loop or an equivalent construct.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that Dietmar Kühl's answer does **exactly** what was asked in the question, but I also agree with Kakadur's comment. A loop is hidden in `std::transform()` so the complexity is the same. Some people will judge, but if there is no direct proof of one way being **better** than the other, I tend to choose the most readable and least verbose version:

```
// create a vector of length of the smaller vector
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> target( A.size() < B.size() ? A.size() : B.size() );

for (unsigned i = 0; i < target.size(); i++)
    target[i] = std::make_pair(A[i], B[i]);
```

P.S.
The code above allocates just enough space for the `target` vector, so that the potential overhead of `push_back` (in case of reallocation) can be avoided.

Comment: you know, there's a potential loop hidden in `push_back` as well

Comment: Well, yes, but If a reallocation happens. Thanks for the hint, I will update my answer

Comment: *"However, for most people this version is a lot more readable and clear"* - Yeah, to those not acquainted with the standard library (and thus C++). And it doesn't really answer the question at all, does it?

Comment: @ChristianRau Your assumption does not make sense. I am acquainted with the standard library and C++, yet I find this code a lot more readable and clear. At least 3 other people upvoted, so I'm not alone. This code does answer the question (I am using "suitable STL functions" - `std::make_pair` for example.) I just refuse to use the STL code unless it has an reduced complexity and better readability. I will not use STL blindly, especially if it looks more verbose and ugly. Simplicity is the key here, my friend :)

Comment: Well, at least you removed the assertion that *"most people"* would find it more readable and clear. But unfortunately it doesn't change anything in the unansweredness of the post. Answers are not there to disqualify the initial question as ill-posed, that's what comments are for. You may very well find his approach inappropriate and provide good reason for that, but this doesn't change anything in the validity and answerability of his question. Certainly *he* wants to use a standard library algorithm instead of a loop, no matter if *you* want it, too.